# ng-bs-daterangepicker default value

Tags: angularjs, date-range, daterangepicker

Im using this date range picker: https://github.com/luisfarzati/ng-bs-daterangepicker

and in my controller I have

```
$scope.myDateRange = {
    endDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()+1),
    startDate: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate())
};
```

in my view I have:

```
<input type="daterange" format="MMM DD" separator="-" ng-model="myDateRange" id="daterange">
```

On initial page load my view has `[object Object]` in the input. My question is, how do I format `$scope.myDateRate` in my controller so that on initial page load i get the correct input rendered

i.e.    `Dec 03-Dec 04`

Comment: How you were able to get this directive to work. I am getting this error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'daterangepicker. All needed resources are fully loaded. regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per documentation for this directive startDate and endDate should be a `moment()`. Try something like

```
$scope.myDateRange = {
    endDate: moment().add('days', 1),
    startDate: moment())
};
```